# Webview loaddata from background in android?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, loaddata

My library will render a webview with a html(JS) string, I call loaddata(htmlString). after that, when the library user want show it, he will add the webview into his page. but the webview html just show something(not full page). if I call loaddata on the Activity's onResume, then it works fine. I guess,  when loadData from background, some JS code or event cannot be trigged, so the render is not correct.

But in IOS webview, the background render works fine.

Comment: I found the question a bit unclear, what is it that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: FIXED.  When the webview did not put into UI(attach to Activity), the webview's size is zero, so the render cannot work. after it has been attach to activity, the webview's onResize will be called and render again, then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If web page using javascript then it may not load. You can enable javascript on your webview object.

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("link");
```

This code will be work.